# How to get a max and min values of a number in a loop with twig?

Tags: for-loop, twig

I am listing some products but i don't want to use max() and min() in query SQL. I tried to use [max()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/max.html) from twig, but it returned an error.

```
{% for product in products %}
   {% set maxValue = max(product.value)%}
   value--->>{{maxValue}}
{% endfor %}
```

**Error:**

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("max() [function.max]: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array")

Comment: What do you want max value of? You are asking for the max of each single product value, did you actually want the max of all products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue resolved**

```
{% set maxValue = 0 %}

{% for product in products %} 
    {% set maxValue = max(product.value, maxValue) %}
{% endfor %} 

{{maxValue}}
```

Comment: this works for max but not for min, min return 0, why?

Comment: for those i need of it, you are to do minValue, here is the syntax.

Comment: {% set mimValue = 99999999999 %}